# laws of logical equivalence and simplfing

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

So I be trying to get my head around the laws of logical equivalence and do be understanding the basic but not when it scales to be harder ones and sadly there is very lil reseores in my first lanuage. Take the example

```
¬∀x ∈ U.(A(x) ∨ ¬B(x)) ≡ ∃x ∈ U.(¬A(x) ∧ B(x))
```

How could you show that without a truth table

Thank you for any help my friend

Comment: Do you know De Morgan's laws.

Comment: thank you for fast respond - i am familar but it don't be clear the besh way to implement it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This equivalence follows from the application of two equivalence principles:

**Quantifer Negation**

$\neg \forall x \ \phi \Leftrightarrow \exists x \ \neg \phi$

$\neg \exists x \ \phi \Leftrightarrow \forall x \ \neg \phi$

So this law effectively says that you bring a negation inside a quantifier, as long as you change the quantifier into the 'other' quantifier.

**DeMorgan**

$\neg (\phi \land \psi) \Leftrightarrow \neg \phi \lor \neg \psi$

$\neg (\phi \lor \psi) \Leftrightarrow \neg \phi \land \neg \psi$

So, applied to your statement, you get:

$\neg \forall x \in U (A(x) \lor \neg B(x)) \overset{Quantifier \ Negation}{\Leftrightarrow}$

$\exists x \in U \ \neg (A(x) \lor \neg B(x)) \overset{DeMorgan}{\Leftrightarrow}$

$\exists x \in U \ (\neg A(x) \land \neg \neg B(x)) \overset{Double \ Negation}{\Leftrightarrow}$

$\exists x \in U \ (\neg A(x) \land B(x))$

Comment: thank you my friend i get it now - the first part was tripping me up

Comment: @JuanCarlos De nada! Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Without using truth tables you can use logical equivalences. There's a great big list of them on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence). Primarily, use DeMorgan's laws. They essentially say how to incorporate negation into logical statements which involve OR, AND, as well as quantifiers.

Relating to quantifiers, we have:
$$\neg \forall x P(x) \equiv \exists x \neg P(x)$$

Relating to logical or/and, we have:
$$\neg(A \lor B) \equiv \neg A \land \neg B $$

You can apply both laws directly to obtain your example. See the step-by-step below:

\begin{align}
\neg \forall x (A(x) \lor \neg B(x)) &\equiv \exists x \neg (A(x) \lor \neg B(x))  \\\\
&\equiv \exists x (\neg A(x) \land \neg \neg B(x)) \\\\
&\equiv \exists x (\neg A(x) \land B(x))
\end{align}